# Scapy Module: netif = rt[4 + mtu_present + prio_present + refs_present + locked] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, macos, scapy, macos-catalina

I'm trying to create a sniffer from the scapy module. I'm running Python 3.7 on macOS Catalina. Assuming that it's something with the macOS Catalina public beta version. I just wanna know what's causing the problem if so. I'm trying hard to understand why scapy throws an index out of bounds trace:

main.py

```
import scapy.all as scapy

p = scapy.sniff()

p.summary()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/sniffer/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scapy.all as scapy
  File "/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/sniffer/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 33, in <module>
    import scapy.route  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/sniffer/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 194, in <module>
    conf.route = Route()
  File "/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/sniffer/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.resync()
  File "/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/sniffer/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 35, in resync
    self.routes = read_routes()
  File "/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/sniffer/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 82, in read_routes
    netif = rt[4 + mtu_present + prio_present + refs_present + locked]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Hi ! This is very likely a bug. Could you head over to https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2134 and add extra details (Scapy version, Catalina build....) among with the output of `netstat -rn` ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug.
Please checkout https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2139 in which it should now be fixed :-)

Comment: I switched over to work around with scapy on linux for a while and then got back to Catalina. It worked for me like a charm after the scapy update v2.4.3. It also works after the Catalina beta update too